# Remove Multiline Script using regular expression

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have following Script which can have multiple occurrences in a post

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    if(typeof(jQuery)=="function"){(function($){$.fn.fitVids=function(){}})(jQuery)};
    customfunction('customfunction_div').setup(
    {"playlist":"customfunction\/jw6\/eM0MzdZ2.xml"}
);
</script>
```

I want to remove occurrences of these scripts using regular expression in preg_replace or preg_replace_callback, also if possible want to check if **customfunction_div** exists at-least once in script.
Please help !

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/84eH8f, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dS1xR7/2)

Answer (score 0):

You should parse HTML with the right tools like `DOMDocument` rather than relying on regular expressions.

Here is a snippet showing how to grab the `script` tags containing the word `customfunction_div` inside and remove them:

```
$html = "<html><head><script type='text/javascript'>\n    if(typeof(jQuery)==\"function\"){(function(\$){\$.fn.fitVids=function(){}})(jQuery)};\n    customfunction('cu').setup(\n    {\"playlist\":\"customfunction\/jw6\/eM0MzdZ2.xml\"}\n);\n</script>\n\n<script type='text/javascript'>\n    if(typeof(jQuery)==\"function\"){(function(\$){\$.fn.fitVids=function(){}})(jQuery)};\n    customfunction('customfunction_div').setup(\n    {\"playlist\":\"customfunction\/jw6\/eM0MzdZ2.xml\"}\n);\n</script></head><body>TEXT</body></html>"; 
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$scripts = $xp->query('//script[contains(.,"customfunction_div")]');
foreach ($scripts as $script) {
       $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/epO5z2)

Here, `//script[contains(.,"customfunction_div")]` is an XPath expression that grabs the `script` tags with contents (`.`) containing *customfunction_div*.

If you insist on a regex, the [`'~<script\b(?:(?!</?script[\s>]).)*customfunction_div.*?</script>~s'`](https://regex101.com/r/dS1xR7/2) pattern should work for you in most situations (as it will match any `<script` open tag, then any sequences not starting with `<script` or `</script` (see `(?:(?!</?script[\s>]).)*`) and then your required value and then 0+ chars up to the first `</script>`), but remember that regex is not the proper tool to manipulate HTML. Only use it as a fallback when you get corrupt HTML.